# Which version of Eclipse shows CSS code hints

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, eclipse

I recently started using Eclipse. Please suggest which which version of eclipse shows CSS hints and provides good support for JavaScript development(Ajax,Jquery).

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/) is an Eclipse plugin. It supports Javascript and CSS mainly.

Comment: After installing aptana... I couldn't launch Web page editor (which support hyml design view)

Answer (score 0):

There's Aptana studio based on Eclipse, or Aptana plugin for Eclipse. This is what you're lookin for.

Have a look at these links:

http://aptana.com/products/studio3

http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html

Comment: After installing aptana... I couldn't open html files Web page editor (which support hyml design view), Getting error: Unsupported content

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Amateras plugin

http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor